# Sharepoint provider hosted app Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect does not work

Tags: development, client-object-model, sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app

I am trying to do.

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(context,relativeUrl)
```

Always get "forbidden" and unauthorized.

However If i use same context and url to do `web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl()` it works as expected.

That assures me, it should not be context or url issue.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [SharePoint 2013 Online App: 403 Response While Downloading Documents from a Document Library](http://tech-karma.blogspot.se/2013/05/sharepoint-2013-online-app-403-response.html) article this error occurs when using oAuth App authentication model  since [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.openbinarydirect(v=office.15).aspx) doesn't pass  App token

The solution is to use [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryStream method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.openbinarystream(v=office.15).aspx) instead as demonstrated in the same article.